# Wrap an img within a div using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my basic code

```
<div class="galleria-image">
    <div class="galleria-layer">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="galleria-image">
    <div class="galleria-layer">
    </div>

    <img src="blah">
</div>
```

I would like to use jQuery to wrap my  element within a new  element so it looks like this:

```
<div class="galleria-image">
    <div class="galleria-layer">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="galleria-image">
    <div class="galleria-layer">
    </div>

    <span class="zoom" id="ex1">
        <img src="blah">
    </span>
</div>
```

I've tried a few jQuery methods but I can't get it right. For example:

```
$('.galleria-image > img').wrap('<span class="zoom" id="ex1"></span>');
```

Any idea what I should be doing?

Comment: Works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/J7pn4/

Comment: You said you want to wrap the image with the `div` but you are wrapping with a `span` so if you are applying say `height` or `padding` you may face some issues as `span` is an *inline* element where `div` is a *block level* element

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/G42WL/1/

Comment: Make sure you execute your script when the **DOM** is ready

Comment: @Anton Still, you never know what he expects, because most of the time, users post something different, they expect something different

Comment: @Mr.Alien Yeah you're right, it's even harder to know what he expects when the code is correct :P

Comment: @Ross Your code still works with the latest edit http://jsfiddle.net/J7pn4/3/ there is something else that causes this problem. Are you getting any errors in the console? Is the markup you posted exactly the same as yours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you dont' need the close `</span>`

also your selector is wrong (>) only gets first children..
see this fiddle..

http://jsfiddle.net/jFIT/6h8Xw/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  alert( $('.galleria-image img').length > 0 ? "exists" : "not exists" );
  $('.galleria-image img').wrap('<span class="zoom" id="ex1">');
});
```

Comment: What do you mean he doesn't need to close the `<span>`? Of course he should. Did you even check what your jQuery generates? A properly opened and closed span tag: `<span><img ...></span>`.

Comment: Wow guys, really? Wrap automatically closes the span tag for you if your using wrap -.-; whats with the downvotes. @DaniëlKnippers https://api.jquery.com/wrap/

Comment: I downvoted because this does not solve the issue, you are just simplifying the code...You wrote the selector is wrong, but it is correct, OP wants to get the first children.

Comment: @JFit I did not downvote, but I thought you were talking about the `</span>` in his HTML, not in his jQuery.

Comment: @Anton check fiddle. it wraps the element. What else is there needed?

Comment: @JFit this is OP's code in a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/J7pn4/ and it does exactly the same thing as your fiddle.

Comment: @Anton So we both wrote the same fiddle to solve the issue? Honestly what else is needed..

Comment: This didn't work for me, I think it might be because I have two .galleria-image divs. I updated my question

Comment: @Ross doesnt matter. it'll wrap all of the results from the selector.

Comment: @JFit strange it doesn't work for me I can wrap other elements just not the img one??

Comment: @Ross are you sure the img exists at that point? do alert or console log the 
$('.galleria-image img').length

Comment: @JFit are there any other ways to target this element? i.e. `wrapInner`

Comment: @JFit how can I check if the img is exists, im running the code after $(document).ready(function()

Comment: @Ross you could do .before and .after ..but that's crazy lol.. does the element exist when you are trying to wrap it?

Comment: do `alert($('.galleria-image img').length);` @Ross

Comment: @JFit I'm not sure if it exists, another script might be placing it there. i.e. the galleria script that is installed on the Magento site on my Magento site.  How can I check to see if it exists when my script runs?

Comment: @Ross just put line before your `$('.galleria-image > img').wrap('<span class="zoom" id="ex1"></span>');`  `alert($('.galleria-image > img').length);`   if you see an alert saying anything > 0 then it exists.

Comment: @JFit I got a `TypeError: $(...) is null` error in my console when I put `alert($('.galleria-image img').length);` into my script

Comment: @Ross check updated.. are you putting in doc ready? + what version of jquery are you using? how is JQuery loaded onto your page? by <script... or by Ajax?

Comment: @JFit yes I'm using `$(document).ready(function()`.  I'm using `jquery-1.7.2` with a script

Comment: @Ross does the img element exist when you are calling the wrap function?

Comment: @JFit I don't think so, I got the `TypeError: $(...) is null ` when I ran that alert

Comment: @JFit Viers answer below almost gets it but not entirly

Comment: @JFit I don't understand how the img does not exist, I can see it in firebug?

Comment: yes if you were to put in a setTimeout around your wrap statement it would probally work.. the image must be loaded asyncronously and does not exist until loaded fully, which is after your code has run.. I can write that for you if you like? to delay the code by like 2 seconds or something..

Comment: @JFit it worked with the setTimeout :). Thanks for your patients. I wonder why my question and your answer got down votes, I think someone was having a bad day & felt left out

Comment: @Ross http://jsfiddle.net/jFIT/6h8Xw/1/ thats delaying the wrap.. .its a horrible method, realistically you should be finding where the image is being set

Comment: Nono, The downvotes are OK i dont mind - anton had a point. Glad you got sorted - just fyi you should really try to find where the img is being loaded instead of doing settimeout, as that will fire after a certain amount of time yes, but if more stuff gets added to the page, the load time will increase..that is why its bad practice.. @Ross

Comment: @JFit good pint, any idea where I can find where the image is loading from. It's a Magento site which is using the gallaria for product images

Comment: @Ross I have no experience with Magento, so the safest method I can think of is to use a global handler, like $.ajaxOptions - AjaxComplete or something to just run that bit of code but be warned it'll happen after every ajax request is done, so check when it fires, and if it fires, make sure you check first if the span is already appended to that image, using like `.parent().is('span')` or something like that. http://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/ is the method im talking about and I'm sure theres some help out there for how to detect the LAST time that occurs.. Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var $galleria1 = $('.galleria-image').eq(1);
var $img = $galleria1.find('img').detach();

var $span = $('<span>', { class: "zoom", id: "ex1"});
$span.append($img);

$galleria1.append($span);
```

Comment: this almosts works but the closing span element is before the img i.e. `<span id="ex1" class="zoom"></span>
</img src="blah">`